# How to share code between binaries and a cdylib in a crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm building an app that hooks some Windows events.
The hook code must be in a DLL for that to work. I set `[lib]` with `crate-type = ["cdylib"]` in `Cargo.toml` and use it in `main.rs`.

```
│   Cargo.toml
│
└───src
        lib.rs
        main.rs
```

It works.

I want to add a second binary, so use this structure:

```
└───src
    │   lib.rs
    │
    └───bin
            bin1.rs
            bin2.rs
```

It works.

`bin1.rs` and `bin2.rs` have some duplicated code that I want to moved to a new `app.rs` module, so I try this:

```
└───src
    │   lib.rs
    │
    └───bin
            app.rs
            bin1.rs
            bin2.rs
```

This causes an error `'main' function not found in crate 'app'`. That is because all files in `bin` are expected to be built as binaries.

I move `app.rs` out of `bin` and try a different structure:

```
└───src
    │   lib.rs
    │   app.rs
    │
    └───bin
            bin1.rs
            bin2.rs
```

With that structure, `bin1.rs` and `bin2.rs` can't access `app.rs`.

Usually the shared code would go in `lib.rs`, but that is my DLL.

How should this situation be handled?

Comment: You can be explicit in your `Cargo.toml` and not rely on convention

Comment: TL;DR the duplicates: Create a Rust library with the shared code. Use that shared code in your binaries, as well as in *another* crate that produces your `cdylib`. A workspace may come in nicely.